# KeyPress Enter for Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

We are doing automation testing and came around with a situation where i need to download the file from the browser .
In Download when the download button is hit we are coming to the system pop for the download where we need to perform the enter operation .

Can some one help us how to perform the enter or keyboard operation currently we are using robot API but it is not working on grid system ,
Here is my code for robot can it be enhanced and used or do we have any alternate way to do it

************ Code *************************

```
public void downloadReportFromMyExport(WebDriver driver, String downloadSufixId) throws AWTException,
            InterruptedException
    {
        String downloadPrefixId =     ConfigProperty.getConfig("downloadPrefixId").trim();
        String[] suffix;
        suffix = StringUtil.split(downloadSufixId, "TR_EXP_");
        String suffixPart = suffix[0];
        String completeId = downloadPrefixId.concat(suffixPart);
        By id = By.id(completeId);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(id);
        element.click();
        Robot pressKey = new Robot();
        pressKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        pressKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        threadSleep("5");
        pressKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        pressKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
        pressKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
        pressKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        logger.info("Downlaod Complete");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In firefox browser,

**Solution-1**

You can change the browser settings so that it saves all downloads to that location without asking.

Refer below link to know to change that setting in firefox.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/startup-home-page-download-settings

**Solution-2**

By using firefox profile setting you can achieve this.

```
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Users\\Downloads\\");         profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah i've encountered the same issue

better change the browser settings to save in a particular path

for handling different browsers like,

in FF,
i've used

in firefox by default the control will be on "OPEN" option so..

```
Robot robot=new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

for IE (to save alt+s,to open alt+O) here im saving the file

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

for chrome

by default,when ever you click dowload button it will save without showing any popups

and i've succeeded hope it helps you

-Ajay

Comment: The Thing is the above code is not working while running automation on grid setup